# How to configure json file in VScode to remote debugging?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, gdb, gdbserver

I would like to have a remote option to debug application. For this purpose, I created the "launch.json" file from the following configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
            "executable": "/home/jakub/repo/app/build/app",
            "target": "193.168.100.1:2345",
            "remote": true,
            "cwd": "/home/jakub/repo/app", 
            "gdbpath": "/home/jakub/repo/ext-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb",
            "autorun": [
                    "info break"
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

First I start GDB Server on the arm board:

```
# gdbserver :2345 app
Process app created; pid = 173
Listening on port 2345
```

then the debugger fires in the vscode but nothing happens, no errors or reaction. I have available only pause, restart and disconnect buttons. The program is definitely correctly built to Debug because I am able to connect through GDB consoles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with this launch configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Attach to gdbserver",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/home/jakub/repo/app/build/app",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "193.168.100.1:2345",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/home/jakub/repo/ext-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb"
}
```

After running:
`gdbserver localhost:2345 app`

It may take a few seconds for everything to connect.